# C go to start of linked list in loop

Tags: c, linked-list

HI I have a linked list as defined as

```
struct process   
{             
    int a;                    
    struct process *next;     
};

typedef struct process node;
```

I have two nodes, 4 and 5 lets say.

I want a loop that goes through the linked list and decrements each node by 1 until its 0.

Any suggestions?

COde I have:

```
  do
  {
    if (arrivalTime->next == NULL)
    {
      // printf("A is: %d \n", arrivalTime->a);
      printf("--       ");
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      //  printf("A is: %d \n", arrivalTime->a);
      printf("--       ");
      arrivalTime->a--;
      arrivalTime = arrivalTime->next;
    }
    //arrivalTime = start;
 } while(1);
```

I can only get the loop to run once.

Comment: I suggest you write a loop and decrement each node by 1 and if there are specific problems, come back here and ask a question

Comment: If you have two nodes the loop runs just fine.

Comment: `arrivalTime -> a = arrivalTime -> a --;` should be `arrivalTime -> a --;`.

Comment: thanks leeduhem. What if its a n node loop

Comment: Make sure you are inserting the nodes correctly. Go back and check to see if they are connected the way you intend.

Comment: Yeap there connected fine. Did a printf on it and pointers are connected fine

Comment: Don't you keep the head of the list? when you get to the end, if you want another iteration then go back to the head.

Comment: yes i did...commented out "arrivalTime = start;". But it goes in infinite loop. I want it to exit the loop once everythins 0

Comment: Why not just set node.a = 0 for each node?

Comment: My guess is that your list is broken. Maybe you should give us a complete working example so we can figure out how you construct it.

Comment: Avoid `do { … } while (…);` whenever possible; it is better to test at the top of the loop (and infinite loops should be avoided when possible, and bottom-tested infinite loops are never a good idea).  You can certainly do that here (`while (arrivalTime != NULL) { …simpler code than you currently have… }`).

Answer (score 0):

```
arrivalTime = start;
while(arrivalTime == NULL)
 {
      arrivalTime->a--;
      printf("A is: %d \n", arrivalTime->a);
      arrivalTime = arrivalTime->next;
 }
```